# establishing parameter values for linear regression power analysis using pwr package in R

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, statistical-power, degrees-of-freedom

I'm designing an experiment and trying to do a power analysis do determine how many participants I will need for my experiment to be able to unearth a small effect size (if feasible). I am not exactly sure how to calculate the values for the parameter values that I feed into the `pwr` package function for linear regression in R.

The function is the following:

```
pwr.f2.test(u =, v = , f2 = , sig.level = , power = )
```

where `u` and `v` are the numerator and denominator degrees of freedom respectively. We use `f2` as the effect size measure. If your arguments are supplied, then the function outputs the fifth argument, in my case `power` which stands for the number of participants. I need advice on how to calculate the values for some of the other parameters.

My significance level is 0.05 and the effect size value is 0.02 for a small effect size. Cohen (1988) suggests f2 values of 0.02, 0.15, and 0.35 represent small, medium, and large effect sizes.

I determine `u` by calculating *p* (the number of predictors) - 1. My factor variables are experimental condition (4 dimensions), stress position (2 dimensions), and vowel (2 dimensions). My continuous variables are frequency and vowel-to-consonant ratio. How do I calculate *p* from this. Do I just count the variables regardless of whether they are factors or continuous variables (in which case I have *p*=5) or do I count each dimension of my factors as 1 (in which case *p*=10)?

I determine `v` by calculating *n-p*, where *p* is the number of predictors and *n* is the number of observations. In my case *n*=60 but I'm not sure how to calculate *p* (see above).

So what I need to find out is how to correctly determine *p* with factors and continuous variables.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is ordinary fixed-effects anova, factors will count as one fewer than the number of levels. If you're including interactions between factors with $k_1$ and $k_2$ levels then it's $(k_1-1)\times(k_2-1)$. You'll also have a constant term (an intercept or a grand mean or similar depending on your coding).

[Alternatively if you make up some data and fit your model you'll *see* how many df it takes]